# Compare key values from two arrays in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays, one is `answers` and the other is `correct`.
Both are exactly the same, the only difference is that the `answers` fills from the user input, so what I want to do is compare this array with the array that already has the solutions so I can give back to the user a score.

I did this function to compare them:

```js
const correct = [{
  slot1: "item1",
  slot2: "item2",
  slot3: "item3",
  slot4: "item4",
  slot5: "item5",
  slot6: "item6",
  slot7: "item7",
  slot8: "item8"
}];

var answers = {
  slot1: "",
  slot2: "",
  slot3: "",
  slot4: "",
  slot5: "",
  slot6: "",
  slot7: "",
  slot8: ""
};
function outputTest(){
    //console.log(answers);
    compare();
}
function compare(){
    for (var[key, value] of Object.entries(correct)){
        console.log(answers[key]);
        console.log(correct[key]);
        if (correct[key] == answers[key]){
            score += 1;
        }
    }

    console.log("total score= "+score);
}

outputTest();
```

But it seems like it doesn't get "answers" array, it shows "undefined", even tho I tested it and it inserts the values correctly before.
Is this the right way to achieve this?

Comment: `answers` is not an array

Comment: @Taplar I noticed that, fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Grab all the keys for the answers and perform reduce on them, with the initial total being zero.
- If the key from the answers matching the key from the object in the correct array, increment the total

```js
const correct = [{
  slot1: "item1",
  slot2: "item2",
  slot3: "item3",
  slot4: "item4",
  slot5: "item5",
  slot6: "item6",
  slot7: "item7",
  slot8: "item8"
}];

var answers = {
  slot1: "",
  slot2: "item2",
  slot3: "",
  slot4: "",
  slot5: "",
  slot6: "item6",
  slot7: "item7",
  slot8: ""
};

function outputTest() {
  compare();
}

function compare() {
  var total = Object.keys(answers).reduce(function(total, answerKey) {
    if (answers[answerKey] === correct[0][answerKey]) {
      total++;
    }
    return total;
  }, 0);

  console.log("total score = " + total);
}

outputTest();
```